# Using FILTER with VALUES (multiple rows error)

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I am learning DAX on the Contoso database provided for The Definitive Guide to DAX book.

I am trying to understand filter context and I wrote this measure:

`CountColor:= COUNT ( 'Product'[Color] )`

I put it into the pivot table where 'Product'[Color] is added to the rows section, here is the result:

| Row Labels | CountColor |
| --- | --- |
| Azure | 14 |
| Black | 602 |
| Blue | 77 |
| ... | ... |

This shows that the filter context in each row is defined by the Color of that row.

When I am writing the following measure, I am anticipating that VALUES only return a unique value of the one color that is currently available in the row of the pivot table and it gets automatically converted to a scalar value:

```
CountColorValues:= CALCULATE (
                     COUNT ( 'Product'[Color] ),
                     FILTER ( 'Product',
                              'Product'[Color] = VALUES ( 'Product'[Color] )
                     )
                   )
```

But putting this measure to the same table, I get the error:
"Calculation error in measure 'Product'[CountColorValues]: A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected."

I created another measure to test if VALUES really return a single value:

```
CountrowsValues:= COUNTROWS ( 
                     CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES ( 'Product'[Color] )
                     )
                  )
```

The result:

| Row Labels | CountrowsValues |
| --- | --- |
| Azure | 1 |
| Black | 1 |
| Blue | 1 |
| ... | ... |

What am I missing when I am trying to make VALUES work in FILTER?

Comment: You're getting this error, because you are trying to compare a scalar value with table, as VALUES returns table, regardless of how many rows it returns. Use IN operator or CONTAINSROWS function.

Comment: As far as I know, if a table has one column and one row, DAX automatically converts it into a scalar value if it is used in an expression. 


CountColorTableToScalar:=CALCULATE(COUNT('Product'[Color]),
FILTER('Product','Product'[Color]=SUMMARIZE(TOPN(1,'Product'),'Product'[Color])))


In this measure the result of SUMMARIZE is passed to the FILTER expression, where the result is intentionally a one column-one row table.

Comment: Sure, but if you're always expecting one value, why use VaLUES in the first place?

Comment: Could you also point me to a doc that talks about this implicit conversion of table to scalar? I did not find it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-data-types

Comment: I am trying to understand what happens in the background in DAX and this case got me confused. Of course if VALUES would return the single color I am expecting, it wouldn't have an effect on the end result because that single color is already in the filter context coming from the pivot table.

Comment: Here you will find under Syntax requirements the mentioning of conversion:
https://learn.microsoft.com/hu-hu/dax/dax-syntax-reference

Comment: Thanks, apparently, it does not work with VALUES. I've checked it multiple ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is supposingly caused by the **Grand Total** of the pivot table.
The context is different there, no color filter is present so VALUES returns every colors, thus the measure is giving the mentioned multiple row error.

Turning off the Grand Totals on the pivot table does not solve the problem, error keeps coming up.

Conclusion is that you have to write your measure Grand Total-compatible even if you are willing to supress it.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, VALUES gets a distinct list of items, so in the following:

```
CountColorValues:= CALCULATE (
                     COUNT ( 'Product'[Color] ),
                     FILTER ( 'Product',
                              'Product'[Color] = VALUES ( 'Product'[Color] )
                     )
                   )
```

'Product'[Color] is trying to equal a list of {'Azure', 'Black' , 'Blue'}, so in affect you are trying to make the rows of 'Azure' equal to a table of the distinct values

For this to work it needs to be changed to an IN, is the [color] value IN the list, not equal to a list.

```
 CountColorValues:= CALCULATE (
                         COUNT ( 'Product'[Color] ),
                         FILTER ( 'Product',
                                  'Product'[Color] IN VALUES ( 'Product'[Color] )
                         )
                       )
```

Comment: I see, but what is the reason that inside FILTER, VALUES is not affected by the filter context, but inside CALCULATETABLE it is?
If I use IN, it lets me pass a table of several rows so it solves the error of multiple rows, but my goal is to understand why does VALUES return all the colors instead of one if the filter context has a filter to a single color value.